# Header Height Not Expanding to the Size of Child Elements

Tags: css

My header element has no height. I have a navigation bar, like so:

```css
nav {
  display: block;
}
.main_nav_bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.drop-down-menu {
  float: right;
}
.drop-down-button {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.drop-down-content {
  width: 100vw;
}
.drop-down-content a {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    Extra Unimportant Stuff
  </head>
  <body>
    <header> Important
      <nav class = "main_nav_bar">
        <div class = "drop-down-menu" onclick = "openDropDownContent()">
          <button class = "drop-down-button"> <i class = "fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> </button>
          <div class = "drop-down-content" id = "drop-down-content">
            <a href = "index.php"> Homepage </a>
            ⋮ Some other similar anchor tags.
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      ⋮
      Extra Unimportant Stuff
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course, the snippet doesn't work, since it is an outline. When I check the elements with the .main_nav_bar and class the .drop_down_menu class (as seen in the respective images), I see that they both have a height:

[Main Navigation Bar has Defined Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTAAa.png)
[Drop Down Menu Has Defined Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZYpT.png)

But the header has no height? As seen in the image:

[Header Has no Defined Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2D8e.png)

Why is this the case? Why doesn't header change it's height to fit the child element? I tried `overflow: auto` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an element has a `position` value other than `static` (default), it is out of the normal flow of the layout. Meaning it's behavior and the behavior of it's ancestors, descendants, and siblings are very different. See this article on [position](https://medium.com/@jacobgreenaway12/taming-the-css-beast-master-positioning-5882bad14458) and of course [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Make your `<header>` fixed not the `<nav>`

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  outline: 5px dashed red;
}
```

Remove `position`, `top`, and `z-index` from `<nav>`

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  outline: 5px dashed red;
}

nav {
  display: block;
}

.main_nav_bar {
  width: 100%;
}

.drop-down-menu {
  float: right;
}

.drop-down-button {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.drop-down-content {
  width: 100vw;
}

.drop-down-content a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  Extra Unimportant Stuff
</head>

<body>
  <header> Important
    <nav class="main_nav_bar">
      <div class="drop-down-menu" onclick="openDropDownContent()">
        <button class="drop-down-button"> <i class = "fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> </button>
        <div class="drop-down-content" id="drop-down-content">
          <a href="index.php"> Homepage </a> ⋮ Some other similar anchor tags.
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    ⋮ Extra Unimportant Stuff
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives header tag height, you are right! I can't believe I coulnd' comprehend something so simple. But what if I would like to have a positioning, like `position: fixed` but when the page loads, I would like all other elements not be covered by nav bar (which works if I don't assign positioning at all). Something, preferably without margin-top to shift below nav bar.

Comment: Yeah `margin` or `padding` `-top` of `<main>`, but to offset the `<header>`  `height` which isn't set explicitly...yikes.  It depends on how responsive you need the page to be.  If you want to start out with desktop/laptop screens, then it'd be safe to set a height in `vh` (`vmin`, or `vmax`), percentages, something relative. If you need mobile screen sizes, you'll need to start small and then build up.